# Botones múltiples

Tags: botón

Si genero botones con un bucle for, es posible que en el llamado de comando pueda pasar algún parámetro para identificar el botón que fue apretado?. Quise hacerlo del siguiente modo y el parámetro que se envía a la función siempre es el mismo. Les paso un código muy simple para que lo prueben y si me pudieran ayudar, estaría muy muy agradecido.
{

from tkinter import *

def valores(a):

```
print(a)
```

root =Tk()

root.geometry('1000x1000')

for x in range(0,10):

```
nombre = str(x)

btn = Button(root, text=nombre, command=lambda:valores(nombre))

btn.grid(row=x, column=1, padx=120, ipadx= 80)
```

root.mainloop()
}

Answer (score 0):

Listo, ya encontré el modo: No sabía que dentro de lambda se podían incluir asignaciones previo a invocar la función.

```
from tkinter import *
```

def funcion(Boton):
print(Boton)

root = Tk()

for i in range(1,21):

```
btn = Button(root, text="Boton" + str(i), command= lambda indice = i:funcion(indice))

indice = i+1

btn.grid(row=i, ipadx = 20)
```

root.mainloop()